# Fresh Symfony2 install doesn't display a single page on production server

Tags: website, deployment, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony2 website on a production server but I am continually being faced by the same problem.

When I go to the website nothing is displayed on the screen. I enter the `/web/config.php` URL in to the browser and nothing (I repeat nothing) is displayed. It's just a blank page. I also go to `/web/` and `/web/app_dev.php` and the same thing happens again. No pages are displayed.

Thinking there must be an issue with the website I'm trying to upload, I have installed Symfony2 as a fresh install (without any of the files I've created). Interestingly enough, when I go to `/web/config.php` it returns this error:

> This script is only accessible from localhost.

I then change a bit of the code so it accepts the IP address I'm using, but then returns to the same problem of displaying nothing.

I haven't got any .htaccess rules applied to this site, and Apache is configured to use the `public_html` as the document root. I had changed this to use `public_html/web` as the document route but changed back thinking this was causing this problem.

**EDIT**
Just checked the version of PHP running on the server (using `phpinfo();`) and the server is runninng PHP 5.1.6, not the PHP 5.3.2 that Symfony needs to get working. I've emailed the guy who owns the server to upgrade this and to see if this makes a difference.

**EDIT #2**
The server is now configured to run PHP 5.3.3, and it has made a slight difference. When visiting `/web/config.php` or even just `/web/` I get an Internal Server Error now (which is more than what I got before!

**EDIT #3**
I used the guide on this [site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup), and changed the permissions to the `cache` folder and `logs` folder. However, yet again, another error is displayed:

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in
>   /home/website/public_html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php
>   on line 214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The first problem I had was that the server wasn't completely clean of PHP 5.1.6. So I uninstalled everything and reinstalled (properly) PHP 5.3.3.

Then, I installed `php-devel` (as mentioned [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php)). I restarted the server, then I had an error message moaning about the timezone of the server. Once this set, everything worked!